# Reverse string using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to understand how the below function *reverseString(const char *str) reverses the string with pointer arithmetic. I have been Googling and watched videos which handle similar cases but unfortunately they didn't help me out.
Could you please somebody help me what may be missing for me to understand how this function works?
I am using Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) with Visual Studio Community 2019. Thank you in advance for your help as always. I appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char *reverseString(const char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str); // length = 10
    char *result = new char[len + 1]; // dynamically allocate memory for char[len + 1] = 11
    char *res = result + len; // length of res = 11 + 10 = 21?

    *res-- = '\0';  // subtracting ending null character from *res ?
    while (*str)
        *res-- = *str++;  // swapping character?
    return result;  // why not res?
}

int main()
{
    const char* str = "Constantin";
    cout << reverseString(str) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
    char *result = new char[len + 1];
```

This line allocates a new string (length of the other string's characters, plus one for the terminating null), and stores it in `result`. Note that `result` points to the beginning of the string, and is not modified.

---

```c
    char *res = result + len;
```

This line is making `res` point to the end of `result`: `res` is a pointer that equals the address of `result`, but `len` characters after.

---

```c
    *res-- = '\0';
```

This line:

- writes a terminating NULL to `res`, which currently points to the end of `result`, and
- decrements `res` so that it now points to the previous character of result

---

```c
    while (*str)
        *res-- = *str++;  // swapping character?
```

These lines:

- loop until `str` points to a NULL
- write the character pointed to by `str` to the destination memory pointed to by `res`, and
- `res--`: decrement `res` to point to the previous location in memory, and
- `str++`: increment `str` to point to the next character of `str`

---

```c
    return result;  // why not res?
```

Result is returned because it points to the (beginning of) the new string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation @uuser9596600! It became clear what I am missing to understand this function. I need to understand how the pointer works.